# dojox.mobile.View performTransition callback broken in 5.0.6

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

After upgrading to worklight 5.0.6 I found that the *performTransition* method of the *dojox.mobile.View* is not calling the callback function when the transition is finished.

```
  registry.byId("view1").performTransition("view2", 1, "slide", null, function(){console.log("hello")})
```

Comment: do you know which dojo versions you are/were using? I recommend checking the docs to see the param list for `performTransition` in the upgraded version, whatever that may be. You might find it simpler (assuming you aren't using a minified build) to just check the output of `registry.byId("view1").performTransition` in the JS console, I often find the comments in dojo are actually more helpful than the docs.

Comment: I tested in JS console before posting. The version is 1.8.1 but since this is worklight I believe IBM has its own compiled version. I have other pure dojo projects with 1.8.0 and 1.8.3 where this works fine

Comment: I didn't mean test the output, I wasn't suggesting you just run the function again, I mean examine the actual function definition, it will have comments at the beginning explaining what parameters it expects.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this with Worklight Studio 5.0.6.20130311-0918 on Mac OSX 10.8.3, deploying on iPhone 5 iOS 6.1.3 using Xcode 4.6.2, and it worked just fine. I wouldn't think this might go different on other OS or device.

Here is the code I've tried, starting from a fresh new Dojo hybrid WL project and aiming to mimic your description:

1/ In test/common/test.html, use this as 's HTML content:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0"
    data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="label:'item 1'"></li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="label:'item 2'"></li>
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view1">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="label:'item 3'"></li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="label:'item 4'"></li>
</div>
```

2/ In test/common/js/test.js, use this version of dojoInit():

```
function dojoInit() {
    require([ "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", 
              "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", 
              "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" ],
            function(registry, ready) {
                ready(function() {
                    var v0 = registry.byId("view0");
                    v0.performTransition("view1", 1, "slide", null,
                        function(){
                            alert("transition done");
                            console.log("transition done");
                    });

                });
            });
}
```

This worked fine for me, including the alert box and the log message in the console.

You say the Dojo version is 1.8.1, but this is not the Dojo version I'm seeing in my fresh install of WL 5.0.6. Can you please check the content of /dojo/version.txt? On my side, it contains "1.8.3-20130207-IBM". Do you have the same? If you don't, and if you upgraded an older WL version using an Eclipse update, I would suggest installing WL 5.0.6 from scratch.

Also, what was the version you were using before upgrading to Worklight 5.0.6? Did you modify your code while migrating, or the change of WL version is the only change you did to your app?

Hope this helps,
Adrian